# CSS borderline wont show in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, border

```
.xboxcontent {
display:block;
 background:#000000; 
 border:3px solid #fff; 
 border-width:0 3px;
 }
 .xsnazzy h1, .xsnazzy h2, .xsnazzy p {margin:0 10px; letter-spacing:1px;}
.xsnazzy h1 {font-size:2.5em; color:#fc0;}
.xsnazzy h2 {font-size:2em; color:#234; border:0;}
.xsnazzy p {padding-bottom:0.5em; color:#eee;}
.xsnazzy h2 {padding-top:0.5em; padding-left:10px;}
.xsnazzy {background: transparent; margin:1em;}
.xsnazzy em {display:block; width:0; height:0; color:#d8d8ee; overflow:hidden; border-top:12px solid #fff; border-left:12px dotted transparent; border-right:12px dotted transparent; margin-left:50px;}
/* hack for IE5.5 */
* html .xsnazzy em {width:24px; height:12px; w\idth:0; hei\ght:0;}
.xsnazzy span {display:block; width:0; height:0; color:#fff; overflow:hidden; border-top:10px solid #000000; border-left:10px dotted transparent; border-right:10px dotted transparent; margin-left:52px; margin-top:-15px;}
* html .xsnazzy span {width:20px; height:10px; w\idth:0; hei\ght:0;}
 .xb1, .xb2, .xb3, .xb4, .xb5, .xb6, .xb7 {display:block; overflow:hidden; font-size:0;}
.xb1, .xb2, .xb3, .xb4, .xb5, .xb6 {height:1px;}
.xb4, .xb5, .xb6, .xb7 {background:#ccc; border-left:1px solid #fff; border-right:1px solid #fff;}
.xb1 {margin:0 8px; background:#fff;}
.xb2 {margin:0 6px; background:#fff;}
.xb3 {margin:0 4px; background:#fff;}
.xb4 {margin:0 3px; background:#000000; border-width:0 5px;}

.xb5 {margin:0 2px; background:#000000; border-width:0 4px;}
.xb6 {margin:0 2px; background:#000000; border-width:0 3px;} 
.xb7 {margin:0 1px; background:#000000; border-width:0 3px; height:2px;}
```

the result of this is:
http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/3583/ffwork.png

in FF.. but ofcourse stupid IE:
http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/6628/ieno.png

Why is this happening and how to solve this..

Theres no images involved.

```
<div class="xsnazzy">
<b class="xb1"></b><b class="xb2"></b><b class="xb3"></b><b class="xb4"></b><b class="xb5"></b><b class="xb6"></b><b class="xb7"></b>
<div class="xboxcontent">
<p>
Hello, my name is Azzyh
</p>
</p>
</div>
<b class="xb7"></b><b class="xb6"></b><b class="xb5"></b><b class="xb4"></b><b class="xb3"></b><b class="xb2"></b><b class="xb1"></b>
<em></em><span></span></div>
```

Comment: In what version of IE? Could you also show the relevant HTML markup?

Comment: Off the top of my head (missing some specific HTML to stare at) I would guess it's an IE box model f*ckup -- e.g. you have an interior box that is actually too big and covering over the border. Also, are there any images involved? IE does not play well with PNGs, so that might be part of it.

Comment: Sorry, this is too complicated for me. I don't have experience with these kinds of unwieldy HTML/CSS contraptions.

Comment: I'm looking at a page I created right now using your code in IE7, and it looks good to me.

Comment: Ugh, CSS hacks. Don't forget the very *first* thing the IE7 team did was to neutralize all the hacks designers had been using to fix ugly bugs in the <=IE6 browsers. If you're still supporting IE 5.5, maybe you need to reevaluate how fancy you want to get with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying a width and height for your .xboxcontent - either in pixels or percentages.